# How can we avoid the shake when we hover over an element and set its border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can we avoid the shake when we hover over an element and set its border? Here is a sample of the code I wrote:

http://jsfiddle.net/s3N2h/

Is there a technique to avoid the shaking? Suppose I hover on File, the borders appears, but that line of text moves a little to the right due to the borders getting rendered. If we hover away it again shakes.

Is there any CSS way of avoiding such shakes?

Comment: +1 for incuding a working example.  And for introducing me to a new scratchpad tool.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The usual solution to this problem is to start off with a transparent border, then give the border a colour on hover.

I've updated your fiddle with this technique:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/s3N2h/1/**

**CSS and JavaScript:**

```
#my_menu li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```
li.hover(function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'white #808080 #808080 white');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'transparent');
});​
```

Comment: The amount of times I've had silly issues like this and this *never* occurred to me *facepalm* +1

Comment: As a note, it is not necessary do this using javascript. You can do it using 100% css using the hover selector.

Comment: @McSas: that's correct, since developers rarely target IE 6 these days.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, when setting the border add a negative margin of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Sass

```
.image{
   border: 1px solid transparant;
   &:hover{
      border 1px solid red;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;